# Checking an array to see if it has dates which have already past

Tags: java, arrays, date, calendar, int

I have an array of task objects. The tasks have due dates. The array is ordered from the earliest date to the latest. I have made a method which is supposed to return the position of the last task that is before today. In other words it has to check whether each task is before today and once it gets to the task that is after today stop and return the position of the last task before today. If the first task is after to day it should return -1. However the method is not functioning as expected. Could I get a reason as to why this is not working:

```
public int overdue() {
    int i = -1;
    this.sort();
    Date Today = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMM yyyy");
    String todayString = dateFormat.format(Today);
    try {
        Today = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy").parse(todayString);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HomeworkDiary.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    while (Today.after(diary[i+1].getDue_Date().getTime()) == true) {
            i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Where is `diary` defined?  Is that the array in question?

Comment: diary it the array in question

Comment: Are you sure that `this.sort` sorts the array as you expect? Did you try to print the array before and after sorting it?

Comment: yes it dose sort the array as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dairy array only contains due dates that are before today, you'll get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Assuming your dairy[].getDue_Date() returns a Date object, I would write something like this:

```
int lastOverDue = -1;
int i = 0;
while (i < dairy.length && Today.after(dairy[i].getDue_Date()) ) {
  lastOverDue++;
  i++;
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: unfortunately this did not work for me. no mater how many overdue tasks there are the while loop dose not run once.

Comment: I think we need more information. This while loop is standard stuff. If it doesn't run at least once then one of the conditions MUST be false.Could you post some more of your code? The dairy class, the dairy declaration?

Comment: Below is an example of the data being compared.                                            An example of the variable 'Today': 'Sun Jul 05 00:00:00 SAST 2015'.
An example of the due date of the first object in my array: 'Mon Sep 07 00:00:00 SAST 2015'. Removing the comparison of dates the loop runs fine however as son as the comparison of dates is added it dose not run at all.

Comment: OK, so the comparison of the dates always yields `false`. 
You should investigate your Today object and the Date's stored in your array. For example, print both dates before you compare them. Please share the result.

Comment: It now works perfectly thank you. I discovered that the data in the array is odered from due latest to due soonest, but when the array is saved to the database it is done backwards. This means that when i looked at the database the data seamed to be in the right oder, however it is sorted in the array in the opposite oder. I have made the following changes to your solution to make it work for me:                                                                   int lastOverDue = -1;
int i = count -1;
while (i > 0 && Today.after(diary[i].getDue_Date().getTime())) {
lastOverDue++;
i--;
}

Comment: Glad to hear that. If I understand your solution correctly, `i` is counting backwards, but `lastOverDue` counts from zero. You might want to check that `lastOverDue` is actually correct after the loop is finished. Unless I misunderstood your question, it might have the wrong index.